# How to compare an array of strings in C++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I am trying to compare two strings in my program so that I can arrange them in dictionary order. I am not allowed to declare an array like this: `string arr[10]`, instead I have to declare it like this: `char arr[10][20]`, where the `[10]` denotes the number of strings and the `[20]` denotes the size of each string.

To compare two strings I tried using something like: `arr[5]>arr[7]`, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: what is "an older version of C++" ? Afaik there never was a official version without `std::string`. And please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The answer is `strcmp(arr[5], arr[7]) > 0`

Comment: OP has clarified the prohibition on `std::string` is not because `std::string` is not supported - it is for pedagogic reasons.

Comment: If this is Turbo C++, please add that tag. Then, char arrays (and pointers to char buffers) are so called C strings. Compare using C string comparison functions. Google "compare strings in C" or something.

Comment: @Sujit OK, well my answer still applies.

Comment: @Sujit Strong advice: don't use tools that are older than you. Turbo C is totally outdated. There are better alternatives today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/strcmp.php

strcmp() should do the trick

Since you are limited to char arrays instead of string literals look at C documentation instead of C++ documentation.  I assume you are a student as I had the same limitations.